# JSON parsing in IE11

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to loop through a JSON object to build connected dropdowns dynamically (year, make, model, vehicle type.) In FF and Chrome, it works great. In IE11, it does not. It doesn't even look like the same object.

The process works like this: do an Ajax call to get the list of model years, makes for the selected year, models for the selected makes, and vehicle types for the selected models. Return that as a JSON string with (among other bits of data) the number of vehicles found matching the criteria. That all works a treat.

Then, iterate through the year, make, make, and type lists to populate the dropdowns. This is where it falls down.

```
    data = arrTemp[1].evalJSON(); // arrTemp[1] contains the return string

    // arrControls is an associative array listing the dropdowns 
    // and their default values, labels, etc.
    for(var ckey in arrControls){ 

        if(arrControls.hasOwnProperty(ckey)){ 

            // cKey is the id of the control, and also the key 
            // for that element of the array. Off of that are
            // properties like "fieldname", "caption"
            // e.g.
            // tmpControls['yearFrom'] = [];
            // tmpControls['yearFrom']['fieldname'] = "@YearFrom";
            // tmpControls['yearFrom']['caption'] = "-- Model Year";
            // tmpControls['yearFrom']['reselect'] = selYear;

            curControl = arrControls[ckey];
            fieldname = curControl['fieldname'];
            caption = curControl['caption'];
            // "data" is the JSON object
            currentPiece = data[fieldname]; // get the data for this particular object

            /*
            // this bit is all just fine in all browsers
            console.log("ckey: " + ckey);
            console.log("caption: " + caption);

            console.log("currentPiece: " + currentPiece); 
            // shows up in FF as [object object][object object]...etc etc etc

            */

            C = $(ckey) // get the control we plan to populate

            // the next line works in all browsers, so I know I'm correctly referencign the controls.
            C.style.border = "1px solid red";

            C.options.length = 0;
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.text = caption;                         
            opt.value = "";                         
            C.options.add(opt);

            // we're good up to here. All this works as it should.

            for(var vKey in p){
                if (p.hasOwnProperty(vKey)) {
                    item = p[vKey];
                    // "inspect" is a function I got from a StackOverflow answer
                    // it iterates the object and tell you properties, functions, etc. of the object
                    // it doesn't look even close to the same between IE11 and FF
                    console.log(inspect(item));

                    opt = document.createElement("option");
                    opt.text = item['displayValue'];                            
                    opt.value = item['fieldValue'];
                    C.options.add(opt);
                }
            }
            C.value = curControl['reselect'];
        }
    }
```

In InternetExplorer 11, inspect looks like this:

```
(function) argumentNames
(function) bindAsEventListener
(function) curry
(function) delay
(function) defer
(function) wrap
(function) methodize
```

In FF/Firebug, it looks like this:

```
(string) fieldValue
(string) displayValue
```

I suppose I could rewrite the whole mess and work with simple arrays, but I'd rather use JSON objects for consistency (as with other projects I've done for this office.)

I've been beating on this problem for three hours and I'm at my wits' end. "fieldvalue" and "displayvalue" are what I want, but there's some difference in the object parsing between IE and FF that I can't figure out.

Comment: Why are you iterating native browser object?

Comment: It just might be issue related to insepct .. did you try to print with simple : console.log( JSON.stringify( item ) ); ?

Comment: @Goran.it I'll try that and see what I get, but with or without "inspect", the fact remains that the code works fine on FF, but not at all on IE, which is to say: the values in the dropdowns are "undefined."

Comment: @Teemu, where am I doing that?

Comment: @BillinKansasCity best thing would be to create some example on codepen or JSFiddle. Without a working example it's hard to tell what's actually the issue there

Comment: Looks like you don't in the code, but you say you're "trying to loop through a [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ..."

Comment: @Goran.it, tried stringify. Got a JSON string in FF, "undefined" in IE. I think I'm going to have to just rewrite the Ajax responsetext to a simple string and split it into an array. As usual, in the real world, supporting IE is more work than it's worth.